# How can I write to console.log from Java in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm building a React Native native module (aka 'bridge') for iOS and Android and need to log to the JS console in native code (Objective C and Java).  This is done easily in iOS using `RCTLog` but I can't figure out how to do it in Java.

I tried `Log.i` but those messages aren't forwarded to Javascript.

The only thing I can think of at this point is to emit a JS event from the Java module and have a handler on the JS side just call `console.log` with the message but that's a pretty roundabout way of doing it.

I would expect to be able to do something like `this.getReactApplicationContext().log("see me in the JS console")` but no dice.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried running `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` in a terminal?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Doing `Log.v("ReactNative", "blah")` I can get it to show in `react-native log-android` but it doesn't show in Chrome Debug Tools console.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to show the messages in the chrome debug console?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as of upcoming react native `0.63` we may be getting the equivalent of iOS's `RCTLog` in Android: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/52b3105f652eca72892f200923e1687f1d995486

The files are in master: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/util

Answer (score -1):

```
 public void logEvent(String text) {
    System.out.print(String.format("logEvent: %s ", text));
 }
```

or just
`System.out.print("Hello");`